# rookie with castle windsor and trying to create implementations of my interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I've created my own project but im failing to spin up implementations of my interfaces using castle!  I've added my `ControllersInstaller`, `WindsorControllerFactory` classes shown below.  My controller is the last snippet of code below.
please help!
thanks,
James

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }
        return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}



public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                        .BasedOn<IController>()
                        .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}






 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IMemberMapper _memberMapper;

    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public HomeController(IMemberMapper memberMapper)
    {
        _memberMapper = memberMapper;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _memberMapper.Map();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

// global file

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }

    private static IWindsorContainer container;

    private static void BootstrapContainer()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer()
            .Install(FromAssembly.This());
        var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you registered `WindsorControllerFactory` as your current `ControllerFactory`?

This is typically done in Globals.asax.cs. If you didn't do it, look at this example: https://github.com/kkozmic/ToBeSeen/blob/master/src/ToBeSeen/Global.asax.cs

More specifically, look at the `BootstrapContainer()` method and where it is called. This instructs ASP.NET MVC to attempt to create any controllers it may need using your newly defined factory. Without this step, you're just using the builtin controller factory.

Comment: ive added a call to the BootstrapContainer() method into application_start() although I get the same problem.  any ideas?

Comment: @JamesRadford have you restarted the application after doing so? Also, a bit of logging helps: try to log calls to your `WindsorControllerFactory` and other points of interest (such as `BootstrapContainer()`) to make sure they really happen.

Comment: ive added logging but the log says the message from above. 'Whitepages.Controllers.HomeController - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your `IMemberMapper` service somewhere. Best place is another installer class for this purpose.